# Incompatible data types in CASE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I am converting a SAS code into Cognos Report Studio version 10 where am stuck at a point where there is data formatting needed.

```
IF SDW_STAT ^= '' THEN PRINCIPAL_BAL = TOT_PRIN;
```

Where '' represnts single quotes without any space

I tried writing a `CASE STATEMENT`:

```
CASE 
WHEN ([SDW_STAT] IS NOT MISSING) THEN ([PRINCIPAL_BAL] = [TOT_PRIN])
ELSE ('') 
END
```

I also tried couple of options like `<> '', is not null, <> ' '` instead of `IS NOT MISSING` but none of them worked. Can you please suggest where I am going wrong?
Pls note: SDW_STAT column has few blank fields and some characters like 'Y' 'S' etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the column outside of the `CASE` statement:

```
PRINCIPAL_BAL = 
    CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(SDW_STAT,'') <> '' THEN TOT_PRIN 
        ELSE PRINCIPAL_BAL 
    END
```

Logically, this will update the principal_bal to tot_prin when sdw_stat doesn't equal blank or null.  If it is blank, then it will just update it to itself.

Comment: Will this also work? If not what is the difference? 'CASE WHEN ([SDW_STAT] <> '') THEN ([TOT_PRIN]) ELSE ([PRINCIPAL_BAL]) END' '

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely the ELSE statement. Your THEN clause is an equation. This will return a boolean, either *true* or *false*. Your else is returning a string. These types aren't compatible. You can test this by changing your ELSE to:

```
ELSE (false)
```

My guess is the data type error will go away.

Can you elaborate on where you are using this code? Is it in a data item or in a filter? There are different rules depending on where your expression is used.

Note: I would comment on the question directly but I'm new and don't yet have the ability.